# I have a problem with firefox-developer. No I can create a firefox-developer.desktop in desktop

Tags: firefox

[image: print terminal]

I'm try to install the firefox-developer edition. Follow this steps.

```
tar -xvf firefox-*.tar.bz2
mv /home/username/Downloads/firefox /opt
touch /usr/share/applications/firefox-developer.desktop
```

Comment: Welcome! You have to run the command with sudo. But... you say you can't create it but in the image the file is there. Can you clarify?

Comment: `touch` creates an empty file only. It requires modification.

Comment: Stop using root to do everything.  Problem #1: Not all home directories are created equal for Ubuntu.  `root` does not get the Downloads, etc. folders by default which're spun via the Desktop environment and installer.  It's **not supposed to be used as an every-day account** so you won't *have* a `/root/Downloads` folder.  You should be doing all of the commands except that `mv` and `touch` command as a user with `sudo` and NOT while logged in as root.

Comment: Problem, solved. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `touch`, you could use `cp` of your existing firefox `.desktop` file and modify it, specifying path to firefox dev binary:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop /usr/share/applications/firefox-developer.desktop

sudo vim.tiny /usr/share/applications/firefox-developer.desktop
```

I've changed the next:

```
Name=Firefox Web Browser Developer
Exec=/opt/firefox/firefox %u
Exec=/opt/firefox/firefox -new-window
Exec=/opt/firefox/firefox -private-window
```

Check your /opt/firefox folder for firefox binaries you could use to launch it.

Comment: Problem, solved. Thank you very much!

Comment: If this answer helped you, you could accept it by tick clicking that is under score triangles.